# Replace text in a string by user input using shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace, scripting

I am trying to replace a couple of words in a string by user input using shell script. I have got the part of the script working but could not complete the full script. Basically, I am checking if a line exists on a conf file. If yes, fine. If not, I am displaying a text to the user and get two inputs from the user to replace them in the text. Finally adding the whole text(with two user inputs replaced in text) at the end of the conf file. Please help me to complete the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#checking if the line exists on the setup.conf file
grep -q -F 'javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar' /path/setup.conf
if [ $? -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Parameters are already set as export on setup.conf"
else 
  echo "export CATALINA_varS="$CATALINA_varS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=YOUR_APPNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=YOUR_TIERNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`""

read -p "Enter the value for -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName : " n1
read -p "Enter the value for -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName= : " n2

appname=$n1
tiername=$n2

#trying to store the whole text in a string
string=export CATALINA_varS="$CATALINA_varS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=YOUR_APPNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=YOUR_TIERNAME -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`"

# Have to replace YOUR_APPNAME AND YOUR_TIERNAME with variables appname and tiername.

echo 'export CATALINA_varS="$CATALINA_varS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=$appname -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=$tiername -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`"' >> /path/setup.conf
```

Thank you.
Kumar.

Comment: Text formatting in OP is unreadable. Could you please edit it, use code tags and not use bold text so aggressively?

Comment: Thanks for the comment vtronko. It is done.

Comment: The problem is unclear from the OP. What is exactly a problem? 

Also, I can't see enclosing `fi` statement, can it be so that you forgot to put it after the second echo line?

Comment: I tested with: echo 'export CATALINA_varS="$CATALINA_varS -javaagent:/var/appdynamics/AppServerAgent/javaagent.jar -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName='$appname' -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName='$tiername '-Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=`hostname`' >> setup.conf

worked in GNU bash 4
close and open single quote again in $appname and $tiername

Comment: Thank you Incrivel. It worked. Now I improvised the script and got another issue. As per the below script I will have to restart twice for two conditions. Instead I want to restart just once when both conditions are true.